# Only Terminal windows appear on TightVNC

Tags: 14.04, amazon-ec2, tightvncserver

I use ubuntu server provided by amazon ec2. I want gui so that i install ubuntu-desktop on server and edit xstartup. But when i connect to my server through TightVNC it shows only terminal windows. Here is the .vnc/xstartup:

```
            #!/bin/sh

            # Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
             unset SESSION_MANAGER
            # exec  /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

            [ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
            [ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
            xsetroot -solid grey
            vncconfig -iconic &
            x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
            x-window-manager &
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the file itself:

```
# Uncomment the following TWO (2) lines for normal desktop:
```

However, in your config, only the first line is uncommented. The xinitrc sript is skipped, because it is still commented.

Uncomment this line, and you should be fine. Without it, starting a gnome-session is futile.

Comment: if i uncomment that line dotted grey screen only appears ?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this dotted grey screen?

Comment: i don't have 10 reputation. so i upload file here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzK7h-AXtpjNbjU5NjlCN3ZObHM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1707906) the permissions of the xinitrc script were broken. Check it for your case